Which word to use for a road ending and joining into another bigger one?
Merge and intersect both seem close to what I need but both have slightly different connotations.
Merge implies something like this

While Intersect can imply both

and

Is there another word that represents/invokes the meaning of just the latter?
Specifically, I am looking to describe a village road that joins into an highway, but not necessarily at an angle as in first picture. It may also join perpendicularly. A couple of real intersections of the kind I mean are these,


The full sentence is: Traffic became increasingly congested as more and more vehicles were spilled onto the highway by the various rural roads that (joined into/merged into/connected into/ended in/intersected with???) the highway.

@Fattie For the image part, done. As for the sentence its in passive voice. Active being (Only mentioning the relevant part) "Various rural roads that ?? the highway spilled more  and more vehicles onto the highway". Not to say your sentence is wrong, I suppose removing 'were' and replacing 'by' with 'from' would also make it a proper sentence.

I hate to tell you this but the new first image is of:  a two lane one-way on ramp (note that all on-ramps are one way) which is merging with a two-lane one-way (obviously) eastbound side of a large freeway. (Note that the massive headlin ementions "merging" and "freeway" :) :) :) )  Neither of the things in the (new) image are a road (they are both "one half of a (ie, divided) freeway").  Hope it helps!

@Fattie Also, if it is not clear, roads intersect with the highway at various angles, not just perpendicularly.

( regarding the grammar issue.  Surely ask or discuss in a separate question. )

"Also, if it is not clear, roads intersect with the highway at various angles, not just perpendicularly"  Yes I absolutely fully understand your question, and I have precisely answered it !!

Your examples are all fine, although "ended in" doesn't emphasise the connection and flow of traffic.

" ... by the junctions of the various side roads to the highway".

Mentioning "side roads" is super-clever

Traffic became increasingly congested as more and more vehicles were spilled onto the highway by the various rural roads feeding into it. Or Traffic became increasingly congested as more and more vehicles spilled onto the highway from the various rural roads feeding into it.

One could recast the sentence to describe the lesser roads as tributaries by analogy with rivers.

My intuition: "roads that connect to the highway" is the most common/idiomatic phrasing. "Connect with" is also high up there. The sentence is still clear with your other options, although some of them are not that idiomatic.

My guess at what you're asking:
IMO, to paraphrase, what you are asking is:

"Specifically, I am looking to describe a [ T-junction ], [ even if the T junction is not literally at 90° ]"

Answer:
T-junction is in fact used even if the minor terminating road arrives at an angle.†
Hence the final sentence you're asking to write would be

Traffic becomes increasingly congested as more and more vehicles spill onto the highway from the various rural roads that end with a T-junction at the highway.

FYI another very simple way to write this is indeed

.. the various rural roads that end at the highway.

If you look at writing describing roads (such as Wikipedia's astounding otaku collection of "articles describing roads"!) you will see that in English it's common to just use "ends at" to describe where, as in your question, a given street or road (or even super-highway, metaphorically) indeed, ends at, finishes existence, terminates into, some more major road. (Observe that such a "conclusion" indeed has to be, topologically, a "T"!  There is no other mathematical or metaphysical possibility! So you can just say "The Going to the sun road ends at the Pacific highway" or whatever, it is superfluous to add the T part.)
(In terms of "how to write this sentence writing tip", the simple full explanation is, simply never try to "make it shorter by finding a magic swr".  Writing is about making it longer and hence clearer.  The capsule version of this is "put swrs out of mind.")

†Road-construction footnote. In cases where T-junctions arrive at an angle, what usually happens is at the "last minute" it kinks in to a 90 degree -ish T.

My first suggestion would have been simply "ends," as it's common to see a road sign "Road ends 0.5 mi," describing not only dead ends but traffic being channeled into a different highway.

@AndyBonner - couldn't agree more.  (in the taxonomy of "SWR horrors" it's the relatively common case where the solution is "Actually you plain do not use a word there!")

The verb tee [with] is also used, informally at least: '... the end of our lane tees with the very busy A40 ....' [Bullet Whisperer; Hitchcocks Motorcycles] The topology is a 3-node (never a crossroads) and the road teeing with the other road/s is in some way of lesser prominence (more minor; perpendicular or oblique to a straight road)..

A beautifully written comment.
